# How to create a dynamic placeholder for a login page?

Tags: javascript, css, web, google-signin, login-page

The current GMail Login Page has an "Email or phone" placeholder text that reduces in size and moves towards the top-left corner of the field on focus. How to achieve something similar using CSS and/or JS?

Comment: By the way, you're talking about an [Angular Material input component](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview). Material is an awesome Angular library that might come handy

Comment: Oh, thank you so much for that. Looks like exactly what I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first of all, welcome to StackOverflow!

It's called "floating labels", and it can be achieved by using CSS alone (which can turn out to be a little hard if you are not really familiar with pseudo-selectors like :focus and :empty) or by using a little of JS, which may be a little easier.

You can take a look at some examples here: https://css-tricks.com/float-labels-css/

Comment: Thanks a lot, Renan! Those examples gave me a fair idea how "floating labels" work. I tried looking into the source of GMail's login page but it became too confusing to figure out because of all the randomly named classes and field names. This was much better to understand.

Comment: No problem! Hope you can achieve a great result. Usually inspecting the code of large applications can be pretty tough.

Answer (score 1):

An easy and simple example for you:

```css
label {
  margin:20px 0;
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
}
  
span {
  padding:10px;
  pointer-events: none;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  transition: 0.2s;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.1, 0.25, 1);
  opacity:0.5;
}

input {
  padding:10px;
}

input:focus + span, input:not(:placeholder-shown) + span {
  opacity:1;
  transform: scale(0.75) translateY(-100%) translateX(-30px);
}

/* For IE Browsers*/
input:focus + span, input:not(:-ms-input-placeholder) + span {
  opacity:1;
  transform: scale(0.75) translateY(-100%) translateX(-30px);
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input placeholder=" ">
  <span>Placeholder Text</span>
</label>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Mordecai. This is perfect!